# C++: Unsigned integer underflow optimization

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer, underflow

I'm having some problem with the following issue in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint8_t l = 200, r = 2, c = 199;

    bool res1 = (l - c) < (r - c);
    bool res2 = uint8_t(l - c) < uint8_t(r - c);
    
    uint8_t ll = l - c;
    uint8_t rr = r - c;
    bool res3 = ll < rr;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << res1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << res2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << res3 << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling int with g++ and clang++ I got

```
 false
 true
 true
```

Now the whole point is that I *would like* to exploit the unsigned underflow , i.e. I expect the second and third answer. I imagine that in the first case, the compiler elide on both side `c`. I would like to know whether there is a robust and compiler-independent way to handle this (without explicitly checking for underflow, which can lower the performance).

Comment: Remember that integer promotion happens in expressions _"... In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments.."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Thank you. But I still do not see why there is difference between `res2` and `res3`.

Comment: But there is no difference between `res2` and `res3`.  Live example showing the intermediate results - https://godbolt.org/z/dz1fvoeax